# Why are all .js.gz files paired with .js files in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I am using rails 5.1.7 with Sprockets

In the public/assets folder we have all the compressed files plus the original .js files:

...389.js.gz
...389.js

Moreover, amongst those, there seems to be one that stores all the js code in the application. That file that stores all the js (or CSS) code of the app is really heavy (Size above 1Mb) and slowing down the app performance. Why is that? what to do for them not to affect the site performance?

Right now the heaviest file in public/assets appears in the report of a web performance assessment application as not being minified, why is so?

Comment: `Sprockets` or `webpack`?, Can you add more context about the doubt + like an example?

Comment: Hi, it's Sprockets, sure I'll add it.

Comment: What version of Sprockets do you use? It changed some of its behavior with version 4.

Comment: In my gem.lock it shows as     sprockets (4.0.0),     sprockets-rails (3.2.1)

Comment: @Gotey, the one big file of JS is I think the main JS file that sprokets compresses all JS code to one file and yes this will be big as per your dependencies. It does so to make only 1 req. Same happens for CSS also. It concats all files, minimize compress it and put it in 1 big file.

Comment: Hi, @cdadityang the problem is that those files are not showing as compressed or minified, lighthouse is telling me they are unused files and that they need to be minified, giving me the potential savings. So I don't get why it's not detecting the compressed version instead.